# Invalid device error returned by cuPointerGetAttribute()

Tags: cuda, nvidia

This question is the same that was previously asked here without being answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996075/invalid-device-error-return-by-cupointergetattribute.

I use a GTX680, CUDA 6.5 toolkit, NVIDIA 340.46 kernel. The GPU has unified addressing capability and compute capability 3.0.

The following code returns `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE`:

```
CUDA_DR_ASSERT(cuMemAlloc(&dev_ptr, size));
CUDA_DR_ASSERT(cuPointerGetAttribute(&tokens, CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_P2P_TOKENS, dev_ptr));
```

Has anyone (Sankar?) had similar problems and found the reason?

edit: this is the code I get the errors from:

```
CUDA_DR_ASSERT( cuInit(0) );
CUdevice dev;
CUDA_DR_ASSERT( cuDeviceGet(&dev, 0) );
CUDA_ASSERT(cudaSetDevice(dev));

CUdeviceptr dev_ptr;
std::size_t size = 2*65536; 

CUDA_DR_ASSERT( cuMemAlloc( &dev_ptr, size ) );
uint flag = 1; // set CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_SYNC_MEMOPS (set to 0 for unsetting this option)
CUDA_DR_ASSERT( cuPointerSetAttribute(&flag, CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_SYNC_MEMOPS, dev_ptr) );
CUDA_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_P2P_TOKENS tokens;
CUDA_DR_ASSERT( cuPointerGetAttribute( &tokens, CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_P2P_TOKENS, dev_ptr ) );
```

Comment: niether one of you have provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which SO expects for this type of question.  Are you trying to create a GPUDirect RDMA interface?  GPUDirect RDMA is [*not available* on GeForce GPUs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#abstract).

Comment: Thanks Robert for your sample code. Yes, I am trying to create a GPUDirect RDMA interface. Since mostly universal virtual addressing is needed, I wanted to try the GeForce until getting a "not supported" error. I implemented it without tokens at first, using the SYNC_MEMOPS option in cuPointerSetAttribute and obtained an INVALID ARGUMENT from the nvidia kernel when calling nvidia_p2p_get_pages. That is why I tried the tokens as well. I am wondering why I do not get the error message "not supported" but instead the "invalid device".

Comment: You asked this question: "Has anyone (Sankar?) had similar problems and found the reason?"  You're getting an error because GPUDirect RDMA is not supported on GeForce.

Answer (score 1):

I have a system with a Quadro GPU at device 0 and a GeForce GPU at device 1.
Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t642.cpp
#include <cuda.h>
#include <helper_cuda_drvapi.h>
#include <drvapi_error_string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int my_dev = 0;
  int dev_count = 0;
  if (argc > 1) my_dev=atoi(argv[1]);
  CUcontext my_ctx;
  checkCudaErrors(cuInit(0));
  checkCudaErrors(cuDeviceGetCount(&dev_count));
  if (my_dev > dev_count-1) {printf("device does not exist\n"); return 1;}
  char deviceName[256];
  checkCudaErrors(cuDeviceGetName(deviceName, 256, my_dev));
  printf("using device %d, %s\n", my_dev, deviceName);
  checkCudaErrors(cuCtxCreate(&my_ctx, 0, my_dev));
  CUdeviceptr dev_ptr;
  size_t size = 256;
  CUDA_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_P2P_TOKENS tokens;
  checkCudaErrors(cuMemAlloc(&dev_ptr, size));
  checkCudaErrors(cuPointerGetAttribute(&tokens, CU_POINTER_ATTRIBUTE_P2P_TOKENS, dev_ptr));
  printf("success!\n");
  return 0;
}

$ g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc t642.cpp -lcuda -o t642
$ ./t642 0
using device 0, Quadro 5000
success!
$ ./t642 1
using device 1, GeForce GT 640
checkCudaErrors() Driver API error = 0101 "CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE (device specified is not a valid CUDA device)" from file <t642.cpp>, line 22.
$
```

Using a GeForce GPU with this mechanism (which is designed in support of GPUDirect RDMA) is *not suppoorted*.  This is documented in the [GPUDirect RDMA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#abstract), which states:

> GPUDirect RDMA is available on both Tesla and Quadro GPUs.

And while it is not the crux of your issue, you may also wish to read the GPUDirect RDMA release notes, that indicate that [this token mechanism was deprecated in CUDA 6.0](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#new-in-cuda-60).